# MVC 4 Looks For Default View Despite Explicitly Setting It

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I've developed an MVC 4 site which runs correctly on my local Win 7 workstation.  My workstation has MVC 4 installed as part of the Visual Studio 2010 bolt-on.

I've deployed the app to my DEV server, which is Windows Server 2008 R2.  Note that MVC 4 is NOT installed onto the DEV server, instead the app uses the MVC bin deployables.  In some cases my `error controller` gets called but I'm not sure why.  Here's the exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Error' or its master was
>   not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The
>   following locations were searched: 
>   ~/Views/Customer/Error.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Customer/Error.vbhtml 
>   ~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Error.vbhtml

The stack trace does not show any line numbers as to where the exception originates.  By the exception it appears MVC is expecting to find view associated with the Customer controller first then checks shared.  However, there is no view in either path and there SHOULDN'T be.

The site uses a global error handler via `Application_Error` in `global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

    ILogger httplog = new HttpLogIt(new HttpContextWrapper(Context));

    if (new HttpRequestWrapper(Request).IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        httplog.Error(1, Enums.ErrorCode.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "An application error occurred during an AJAX request.  See exception for details.", ex, false);
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
        {
            errorMessage = "We apologize, the website has experienced an error.  Please try again."
        }));
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        httplog.Error(1, Enums.ErrorCode.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "An application error occurred.  See exception for details.", ex, false);
    }


    Response.Clear();
    // Clear the error on server.
    Server.ClearError();
    // Avoid IIS7 getting in the middle
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

    // try to send error info to Error controller
    RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
    // maintain current url, even if invalid, when displaying error page
    routeData.Values.Add("url", Context.Request.Url.OriginalString);

    if (ex is HttpException)
    {
        HttpException httpException = ex as HttpException;
        switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
        {
            case 404:
                // Page not found.
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "Http404");
                break;

            default:
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "Unavailable");
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "Unavailable");
    }

    // Pass exception details to the target error View.
    var model = new HandleErrorInfo(ex, routeData.Values["controller"].ToString(), routeData.Values["action"].ToString());
    routeData.Values.Add("errorinfo", model);

    // Call target Controller and pass the routeData.
    IController errorController = new ErrorController();
    errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
}
```

The re-route from the global handler to the Error controller lands in the the Error controller where it explicitly sets the views to use:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    private ILogger _httplog;

    public ErrorController()
    {            
        _httplog = new HttpLogIt(this.HttpContext, this.RouteData);
    }

    public ActionResult Http404()
    {
        if (this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["errorinfo"] != null)
        {
            HandleErrorInfo errorinfo = null;
            errorinfo = (HandleErrorInfo)this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["errorinfo"];
            _httplog.Warn(1, Enums.WarningCode.PAGE_NOT_FOUND, "A global application exception was handled and the end user was redirected to the Error Controller with Http404 Action.");
        }

        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        // explicitly set the View below
        return View("Error404");
    }

    public ActionResult Http500()
    {
        if (this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["errorinfo"] != null)
        {
            HandleErrorInfo errorinfo = null;
            errorinfo = (HandleErrorInfo)this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["errorinfo"];
            _httplog.Error(1, Enums.ErrorCode.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "A global application exception was handled and the end user was redirected to the Error Controller with Http500 Action.", errorinfo.Exception, true);
        }

        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        // explicitly set the View below
        return View("Unavailable");
    }


    public ActionResult Unavailable()
    {

        if (this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["errorinfo"] != null)
        {
            HandleErrorInfo errorinfo = null;
            errorinfo = (HandleErrorInfo)this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["errorinfo"];
            _httplog.Error(1, Enums.ErrorCode.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "A global application exception was handled and the end user was redirected to the Error Controller with Unavailable Action.", errorinfo.Exception, true);           
        }

        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        // explicitly set the View below
        return View("Unavailable");
    }
}
```

I added add'l logging in each method to try to find the culprit but to no avail.  What's odd is that, thru adding extra logging, the global error handler is NOT firing when this exception is thrown and logged!

Has anyone encountered something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added some more logging and found the culprit.  In the `Error` controller, `Http404` action, I added the following logging block

```
_httplog.Info(String.Format("Controller is {0}, Action is {1} and URL is {2}.",
                RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(),
                RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(),
                RouteData.Values["url"].ToString()));
```

The resulting log showed:

> Message: Controller is Error, Action is Http404 and URL is __utm.gif.

This is a Google Analytics image file and I had seen this `gif` call in my server dumps during performance monitoring, however, didn't correlate it with my `Error` controller firing.  Since my site is a subsite and the parent site uses `GA`, the `urchin` script was enabled in the DEV env.

Here's why it fired - in the `RouteConfig.cs`, the very last entry handles all bad URLs and routes them to the `Error` controller, `Http404` action, like so:

```
routes.MapRoute("BadRoute", "{*url}", new { controller = "Error", action = "Http404" });
```

This is to handle any bad URL path and keep the current URL in place - instead of showing an `IIS 404` or a `customerror` html page.

This answers the question as to why my `Error` controller got called outside of the code, however does not answer why the MVC framework went looking for a different error controller with a matching default view.  The fix for that entailed disabling the following line in my `FilterConfig.cs`

> filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());

This was firing despite the app handling errors in the global.asax.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line in your web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On" />
```